# how to select from 4 tables using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join

i a using MYSQL database and i have a task to select from 4 tables that are :

**site_locaion:**

- siteID(PRIMARY KEY)
- locationName
- lat
- long

**employee:**

- employeeID(PRIMARY KEY)
- employeeName

**inspection_info:**

- inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)
- inspectionDate
- employeeID

**inspection_site:**

- inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)
- siteID(PRIMARY KEY)

  WHAT i want is to select  the **locationName** and the **employeeName** and the **inspectionDate**

**to be able to know at this location this employee did an inspection at that date.**

Comment: what have you tried? Do you understand about JOINs in SQL? We're not really here to write something for you from nothing (although it's not a big query really) especially when you could easily look up the principles of how to do it online already, but if you have some code which isn't working properly we can happily help you to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't checked the syntax, but it should be something like this:

    `SELECT 
    l.locationName,
    e.employeeName,
    i.inspectionDate
    FROM
    site_location l
      JOIN inspection_site s
        JOIN inspection_info i
          JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID = i.employeeID
        ON i.inspectionID = i.inspectionID
      ON s.siteID = l.siteID`